# Which of the two sentences is natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

Sentence 1: You are as good as you think **you are**.

Sentence 2: You are as good as you think.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much common to what you asked [previously here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/as-much-as-me-as-much-as-i/30753#30753)

Both sentences are common though the second one is a truncated form. Though the first one is a complete sentence (as compared to the second one), but the second one is also easily understood in that context.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the first one sounds more natural. The second one seems truncated in some way, and I am left with a feeling that, though the point got across, the sentence was grammatically incorrect.