# "as much as me" & "as much as I"

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns, as, case

Sentence 1: He doesn't earn as much ***as* me**.

Sentence 2: He doesn't earn as much ***as* I**.

In sentence 1, the second "as" is a preposition so it is followed by an object pronoun.
In sentence 2, the second "as" is a conjunction, and the complete sentence should be "He doesn't earn as much as I earn". Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer putting *I* because it's used in its truncated form.

> He does not earn as much as I *(do)*.

However, I think it's a matter of register, the style you write. Because I have also observed authors using *me*. In modern English, either seems okay as they convey the message.

Comment: I agree that it's a matter of register.  "As I" sounds very formal to me.  "As me" sounds normal.  If you say the latter, it's clear that *as* is a preposition rather than a conjunction (it can be either one) and nothing is left out.

Answer (score 1):

> He doesn't earn as much as I/me.

There is some ambiguity as to whether "as" is used here as a preposition or a correlative conjunction. In the latter case, the clause "as I am" is being shortened to the elliptical clause "as I." For this reason, traditional prescriptivists will tell you that "as me" is incorrect here.

It's unclear to me how this shakes out historically or in the best writers, or whether it's one of those 19th-century Latinisms that is foreign to English.

But the traditionalist rule does seem to add precision sometimes:

> My husband has an aluminum bat, and he hits balls as often as me.

Does this this mean that he hits his wife with the bat every weekend?

> My husband has an aluminum bat, and he hits balls as often as I.

Here there is no ambiguity. If it sounds too stiff and formal in speech, then you can say "as I do."

Answer (score 0):

Using 'I' without the trailing past tense verb is a standard construction where the verb is understood but not spoken.

"So, he earned as much as I" is acceptable, andmay be preferable in certain contexts.